# how to obtain router information

Tags: c++, winapi, router

I want to obtain router information like vendor name, firmware, channel etc. I have used WlanGetAvailableNetworkList() to get the information, but it does not provide all the information mentioned above. 
Is there any API which provides mentioned information or does it stored anywhere on the PC?

Comment: You mean information about the access point? Router and access point are not always the same device. Also, as `WlanGetAvailableNetworkList()` is a Windows function, I assume you are on Windows, using WinAPI? You should add this to your tags.

Comment: Noted and added the winapi tag. I want to extract information about Router. e.g vendor name is cisco etc.